# Symfony2 Subforms

Tags: php, symfony

So, im trying to embed one form in another without creating a class for the forms. Heres what ive got

```
    $form = $this
        ->buildForm('UserAlert', $alert)
        ->add('Alert', 'entity', array('class' => 'Blah\MgmtBundle\Entity\Alert', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => true))
        ->add('Site', 'entity', array('class' => 'Blah\MgmtBundle\Entity\Site', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Keyword', 'entity', array('class' => 'Blah\MgmtBundle\Entity\Keyword', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Variant', 'entity', array('class' => 'Blah\MgmtBundle\Entity\Variant', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Name', 'text');


    $uac = $alert->getUserAlertConfig();
    $subform = $this
        ->buildForm('UserAlertConfig', $uac)
        ->add('EmailAlert', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'), 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Email Alerts'))
        ->add('EmailHours', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Email Alert Hours'))
        ->add('TextAlert', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'), 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Text Alerts'))
        ->add('TextHours', 'text', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Text Alert Hours'));

    $form->add($subform);
    $form = $form->getForm();
```

however, on the `getForm()` function, its saying

```
Neither property "form" nor method "getForm()" nor method "isForm()" exists in class "Blah\MgmtBundle\Entity\UserAlert"
```

anyone have any idea how im supposed to get this to work using the quickloading stuff?

heres buildForm

```
public function buildForm($model = '', $data)
{
    if (empty($model)) {
        throw new \Exception("Must define a model");
    }
    return $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, array('data_class' => "\\Blah\\MgmtBundle\\Entity\\$model"));
}


    Stack Trace
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php at line 314    
at PropertyPath ->readProperty (object(UserAlert), '0') 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php at line 191    
at PropertyPath ->getValue (object(UserAlert)) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 64   
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForm (object(UserAlert), object(Form)) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 55   
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms (object(UserAlert), array('_token' => object(Form), 'Alert' => object(Form), 'Site' => object(Form), 'Keyword' => object(Form), 'Variant' => object(Form), 'Name' => object(Form), 'form' => object(Form))) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 404    
at Form ->setData (object(UserAlert)) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 659    
at FormBuilder ->getForm () 
in /mnt/www/reporting/src/Blah/MgmtBundle/Controller/AlertController.php at line 96    
at AlertController ->editAction ('1') 
in at line     
at call_user_func_array (array(object(AlertController), 'editAction'), array('1')) 
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 438    
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 416    
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpKernel.php at line 44    
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 612    
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in /mnt/www/reporting/web/app_dev.php at line 12
```

Comment: Is this controller code? Or custom form type code?

Comment: And the `buildForm` method is defined where? Could you post its source code?

Comment: Could you post some info about the exception being thrown? The stack trace?

Comment: Symfony turns it into html, so thats all i can get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up creating an interface for the subform and adding it like this

```
    $form = $this
        ->buildForm('UserAlert', $alert)
        ->add('Alert', 'entity', array('class' => 'Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Entity\Alert', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => true))
        ->add('Site', 'entity', array('class' => 'Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Entity\Site', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Keyword', 'entity', array('class' => 'Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Entity\Keyword', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Variant', 'entity', array('class' => 'Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Entity\Variant', 'property' => 'name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('Name', 'text');

    $uac = $alert->getUserAlertConfig();



    $subform = $this->buildForm('UserAlertConfig', $uac, new \Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Form\UserAlertConfig)
        ->add('EmailAlert', 'choice', array('choices' => array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'), 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Email Alerts'))
        ->add('TextAlert', 'choice', array('choices' => array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes'), 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Text Alerts'));

    $form->add($subform, '', array('label' => ''));
    $form = $form->getForm();
```

if anyone can find an easier way without creating interfaces, let me know

Comment: I would say you should not need `getForm()` as `$form` already IS your form. `getForm()` is used with the `FormBuilder` isn't it ?

Comment: `buildForm` is returning a `FormBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$form->add('The name of the UserAlertConfig property in the UserAlert entity', $subform);
```

If you pass a FormBuilder object to the add method without specifying the property name, it uses the name of the FormBuilder object (which is `'form'`) as the property name. There's no property named `form` in the UserAlert entity.

Comment: alright, that wasnt working, but when i flip it, `$form->add($subform, 'userAlertConfig');` it gets me a bit closer.

now im having a problem with proxies lol

`Expected argument of type "\Neokeo\MgmtBundle\Entity\UserAlert", "Proxies\NeokeoMgmtBundleEntityUserAlertConfigProxy" given`